# Rails.application.credentials.dig(:secret_key_base) returning nil in Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my project on Heroku for production testing.

In development environment I can use `Rails.application.credentials.dig(:secret_key_base)` to get secret key base for JWT authentication:

```rb
    # example
    def decode(token)
      key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:secret_key_base)
      JWT.decode(token, key)
    end
```

But when I use that in Heroku it returns "nil". I tried entering it in the console via `rails console` and it returned "nil".

What do I do to make it available in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to `decrypt` the credentials file, you need to have `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` set in your `environment`.

You need to get the value from `config/master.key` and add it to the environment in Heroku's dashboard.

Comment: Yup and good luck when you precompile assets for production. It won't work.